# Passing a pointer to a vector

Tags: c++

I'm exploring a c++ library and cant figure out why its examples are written as they are.
In the example they do the following

```
 std::vector<unsigned int> vec(count);
 someFunc(&vec[0]);
```

while the fucion is define as

```
void someFunc(unsigned int* a);
```

why are the examples passing a reference to the first element of the vector and not the whole vector. Inst this code the same ?

```
 someFunc(&vec);
```

Edit: I should have provided more contex. I simplified the case, but this has proven a bad descision. The function is supposed to simplify a mesh, the vec is a list of all the indicies of the mesh. Presumably somewhere in the code that pointer is used to iterate over the rest of the indicies ?

Comment: `&vec[0]` is a pointer to the first element. `&vec` is a pointer to a `std::vector<unsigned int>`. Those are two completely different types of pointers. There are no references here

Comment: You may want to consult one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: why the function takes a pointer to a single element rather than a reference to the whole vector is not clear from the provided context.

Comment: Presumably `someFunc` accepts a pointer to a single `unsigned int` so that it can potentially modify it.  That being the case why pass a reference/pointer to the whole vector?

Comment: The vector is not passed by reference. The ampersand, "&", has three different meanings. In a type, it means "reference"; as a unary operator, it means "address of" (this is the case here); as a binary operator, it means "bitwise and".

Comment: `someFunc(vec.data())` might be clearer.

Comment: to iterate the vector the function would also need the size. A pointer does not carry information on the size of the array

Comment: Like an array a pointer to the first element of a vector is all you need to point to the entire array that the vector abstracts.  You  do need a size parameter to know where the end of the array is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they have written their example like they have is that `someFunc()` takes in a `unsigned int*` type (a pointer to an unsigned int). The reason they call it as:

```cpp
someFunc(&vec[0]);
```

and not

```cpp
someFunc(&vec);
```

is because a `std::vector` is not like a C-style array (say `unsigned int arr[]`) where `arr` can be boiled down a `unsigned int*` to the first element in the array but is rather a class/struct that acts as a resource handle to some dynamic memory they you access `std::vector` interface. Thus, like any class in C++, calling `foo(&A)` (where `A` is some class instance/object) would return a pointer to the object itself [1].

In their example they have accessed the first element of the `vec` like a C-style array (using the overloaded `operator[]`) which is a reference. They then use the C-style unary-prefix ampersand operator (with the signature `&A`) to access the address of the value obtained through the index operator.

There example might be clearer if they used `std::vector::data()` which returns a pointer to the starting address of the memory owned by the vector or using `std::addressof()` (although the latter can be verbose).

```cpp
someFunc(vec.data());

/// or ...

someFunc(std::addressof(vec[0]));
```

[1] Note: This may not be the case if the class/struct in question has overloaded the `&` operator to behave differently. `std::vector` does not in this case.

## Links

- [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [Member Access Operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)
- [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

Comment: *"calling `foo(&A)` (where A is some class instance/object) would return a pointer to the object itself."* - unless said class overrides the address-of operator :P

Comment: @UnholySheep indeed :). I'll make another note

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the library function someFunc was written with a C-style array as an argument, i.e. you just pass a pointer to the first element (not a reference). As the pointer is typed, the addresses of the next elements can be computed by the function. But their number must be known elsehow.